# What is the risk of enabling virtualization on my notebook?

Tags: hardware-virtualization, bluestacks

I have installed Bluestacks the android emulator, the app asked for enabling virtualization, i did some search and found that enabling it can be a security issue..i could not understand this part!!

So what can be the risk of enabling virtualization? and should i enable it in my case especially it really enhanced performance of my app??

Comment: I think whenever you enable features, you inherently increase your risk level. It is a natural part of computing.  In other words, the statement that enabling a feature could be a security risk is true for just about anything, however unlikely that is. Virtualization is needed to run your virtual machines.

Comment: thank you , virtualization really enhanced the performance of the app, but i decided to disable it back after i read that info about security, thank you!!

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @Appleoddity It's too general, as a kind of saying, please, be more specific.